# Finite-Temperature $\phi^{4}$ theory - Why is the massless $T\neq 0$ contribution diverging?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, temperature, renormalization, integration, interactions

I'm following Chapter 3 of Kapusta and Gale's Finite-Temperature Field Theory here.

I'm considering the following integral (the unrenormalized self-energy evaluated at zero-four momentum):
$$
\mathcal{A} \ = \ T \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \int \frac{d^{3}\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^{3}} \frac{1}{\big[ (2 \pi n T)^{2} + \mathbf{p}^{2} + m^{2} \big]^{2}}
$$

After doing the summation, and transforming to polar coordinates, and playing around with things, I've managed to massage the above into the form $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}_{0} + \mathcal{T}$, where:
$$
\mathcal{A}_{0} \ = \ \int \frac{dp_{4} d^{3}\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^{4}} \frac{1}{( p_{4}^{2} + \mathbf{p}^{2} + m^{2} )^{2} } \\
\mathcal{T} \ = \ \frac{1}{ 2 } \int \frac{d^{3}\mathbf{p}}{(2\pi)^{3}} \frac{1}{(\mathbf{p}^{2}+m^{2})^{3/2}} \left[ \frac{\tfrac{\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^{2}+m^{2}}}{T}+1}{e^{\tfrac{\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^{2}+m^{2}}}{T}} - 1} + \frac{\tfrac{\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^{2}+m^{2}}}{T}}{\left( e^{\tfrac{\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^{2}+m^{2}}}{T}} - 1 \right)^{2}} \right]
$$

This is pleasant because the first integral is exactly the zero-temperature contribution (after a Wick rotation) - this is of course divergent, but can be regulated with a momentum cutoff no problem.

The second integral contains the $T \neq 0$ physics - it has some Bose-Einstein distributions in it, as it should.

**Setting $m=0$**, the integral $\mathcal{A}_{0}$ now has an ultraviolet divergence, as well as an infrared divergence. We can introduce UV and IR cutoffs to deal with this.

Furthermore, $m=0$ in $\mathcal{T}$ eventually gives us the following:
$$
\mathcal{T} \ = \ \frac{1}{ 4 \pi^{2} } \int_{0}^{\infty} dz \left[ \frac{1+\tfrac{1}{z}}{e^{z} - 1} + \frac{1}{( e^{z} - 1 )^{2}} \right]
$$

This integral is very badly divergent for small $z = R/T$. (It seems to converge fine for large $z$ though)

**My QUESTION:** It seems that the $\mathcal{T}$ integral diverges when I set $m=0$. Why is this? I thought that there should be no new divergence introduced for the $T\neq0$ contributions. If this is okay, should I be regulating this integral with an infrared cutoff?

Comment: If I remember correctly Kapusta has pleanty of sections dealing with resummations of IR divergences. There should be something about this in the same or subsequent chapters